# Model doesn't mirror correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, armature

One of my first models from several months ago, when I began with Blender, doesn't work with a mirror modifier properly. While tabbing between Edit and Object modes, the object origin remains in place, while the mesh location is different on the x-axis by a half a blender unit. In *Edit Mode* the mesh favors the right as in +5, while in *Object Mode* it is -1! I did try clearing scale, rotation and location. Any ideas?

Here is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33015

Comment: Essentially when attempting to mirror the gap between the models center is large in edit mode while it's near perfect in object mode?

Comment: Here is a blend file I appreciate any assistance  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33015

Comment: The model is also being rotated by the armature so it's not actually upright.  When the armature is deleted; the model rotates slightly along the X and Y axis.  I think you may have to start over by removing the parenting, clearing the transform, realign the model and then add the mirror modifier before re-doing the rig.

Comment: Start over is what I feared I would need to do considering it was my first model, learning model while I like to hurry through things..I really very much appreciate your assistance...I guess saying "Thanks" is the only way to provide gratitude!

Comment: The reason that you object looks ok in object but not in edit mode is that the parented armature is displaced. You could try to remove it, and enable clipping in the mirror modifier. Than move the original (right) part of the mesh toward center. And setup the armature again.

Comment: That sounds like a good possible alternative...Much thanks!!!